# Loop through multiple columns with case-then

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using oracle sql developer and have a query whereby I want to apply the same query on different columns, then stack the resulting output into a single data table.

For example, the query looks like the following:

```
select BG_TURNOVER, MARKET, count(*)
FROM( SELECT (CASE 
   WHEN sports_returns_l90d = 0
   THEN 'sports_returns_l90d_0'
    WHEN sports_returns_l90d > 0 AND sports_returns_l90d <= 500
    THEN 'sports_returns_l90d_0_500'
    WHEN sports_returns_l90d > 500 AND sports_returns_l90d <= 1000
    THEN 'sports_returns_l90d_500_1000'
    WHEN sports_returns_l90d > 1000 AND sports_returns_l90d <= 2500
    THEN 'sports_returns_l90d_1000_2500'
    WHEN sports_returns_l90d > 2500 AND sports_returns_l90d <= 5000
   THEN 'sports_returns_l90d_2500_5000'
   ELSE 'sports_returns_l90d_5000+'
END) AS BG_TURNOVER, MARKET
FROM PRODUCT_TABLE ) group by BG_TURNOVER, MARKET;
```

Which looks like:

```
BG_TURNOVER         MARKET          count
sports_returns_l90d_5000+       Romania         497864
sports_returns_l90d_1000_2500   Hungary         2986
sports_returns_l90d_0           Belgium Dutch   14103
sports_returns_l90d_5000+       Intl French     6745
...
```

However, I wanted to apply multiple columns in place of `sports_returns_l90d`. Then have the string match that column name.

For example:

```
select BG_TURNOVER, MARKET, count(*)
FROM( SELECT (CASE 
   WHEN X = 0
   THEN 'X_0'
    WHEN X > 0 AND X <= 500
    THEN 'X_0_500'
    WHEN X > 500 AND X <= 1000
    THEN 'X_500_1000'
    WHEN X > 1000 AND X <= 2500
    THEN 'X_1000_2500'
    WHEN X > 2500 AND X <= 5000
   THEN 'X_2500_5000'
   ELSE 'X_5000+'
END) AS BG_TURNOVER, MARKET
FROM PRODUCT_TABLE ) group by BG_TURNOVER, MARKET;
```

Whereby X takes the column names: `sports_return_l90d, sports_returns, bingo_returns`, is there a way to iterate over all of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the `sports_return_l90d, sports_returns, bingo_returns` values in different columns such as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE product_table ( sports_return_l90d, sports_returns, bingo_returns, market ) AS
SELECT 1000, 5500, 1, 'AAA' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

Then you can use:

```sql
SELECT type ||
       CASE 
       WHEN bg_turnover = 0
       THEN '_0'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 0 AND bg_turnover <= 500
       THEN '_0_500'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 500 AND bg_turnover <= 1000
       THEN '_500_1000'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 1000 AND bg_turnover <= 2500
       THEN '_1000_2500'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 2500 AND bg_turnover <= 5000
       THEN '_2500_5000'
       ELSE '_5000+'
       END AS BG_TURNOVER,
       MARKET, 
       count(*)
FROM   PRODUCT_TABLE
UNPIVOT (
  bg_turnover FOR type IN (
    sports_return_l90d AS 'sports_return_l90d',
    sports_returns     AS 'sports_returns',
    bingo_returns      AS 'bingo_returns'
  )
)
GROUP BY
       type,
       CASE 
       WHEN bg_turnover = 0
       THEN '_0'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 0 AND bg_turnover <= 500
       THEN '_0_500'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 500 AND bg_turnover <= 1000
       THEN '_500_1000'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 1000 AND bg_turnover <= 2500
       THEN '_1000_2500'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 2500 AND bg_turnover <= 5000
       THEN '_2500_5000'
       ELSE '_5000+'
       END,
       MARKET;
```

Which outputs:

| BG_TURNOVER | MARKET | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sports_return_l90d_500_1000 | AAA | 10 |
| sports_returns_5000+ | AAA | 10 |
| bingo_returns_0_500 | AAA | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5hFcHPHc)