# Case-when loop with correct percentages

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently asked how to implement a loop with [case-when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75137155/loop-through-multiple-columns-with-case-then), however, when I attempt to get the percentage of each group segment relative to all the total counts in that group. I get incorrect values, for example, the first group will all match 100%, whereas, the other groups will not total 100% for their segment.

For example, here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT  type ||
       CASE 
       WHEN bg_turnover = 0
       THEN '_0'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 0 AND bg_turnover <= 500
       THEN '_0_500'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 500 AND bg_turnover <= 2500
       THEN '_500_2500'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 2500 AND bg_turnover <= 5000
       THEN '_2500_5000'
       ELSE '_5000+'
       END AS BG_TURNOVER,
       count(*) AS Total, Market, round((count(*)/(select count(*) from  product_table where market = 'DK')), 2) AS Percentage
FROM   product_table 
UNPIVOT (
  bg_turnover FOR type IN (
    BINGO_TURNOVER AS 'BINGO_TURNOVER',
    BINGO_TURNOVER_L10D     AS 'BINGO_TURNOVER_L10D',
    CASINO_TURNOVER      AS 'CASINO_TURNOVER',
) where market = 'DK'
GROUP BY
       type,
       CASE 
       WHEN bg_turnover = 0
       THEN '_0'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 0 AND bg_turnover <= 500
       THEN '_0_500'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 500 AND bg_turnover <= 2500
       THEN '_500_2500'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 2500 AND bg_turnover <= 5000
       THEN '_2500_5000'
       ELSE '_5000+'
       END, Market;
```

Will print something out like the following:

```
BINGO_TURNOVER_0                    177540  DK  0.91
BINGO_TURNOVER_0_500                15789   DK  0.08
BINGO_TURNOVER_2500_5000            411     DK  0
BINGO_TURNOVER_5000+                1007    DK  0.01
BINGO_TURNOVER_500_2500             1423    DK  0.01
BINGO_TURNOVER_L90D_0               70474   DK  0.36
BINGO_TURNOVER_L90D_0_500           2586    DK  0.01
BINGO_TURNOVER_L90D_2500_5000       80      DK  0
BINGO_TURNOVER_L90D_5000+           91      DK  0
BINGO_TURNOVER_L90D_500_2500        299     DK  0
```

The first group totals 100% where the second group and onwards do not, for example, the second group here only totals 37% when it should be all totalling 100%. Where do I go wrong with this?

Comment: What percent do you want? currently you are dividing count over pivoted number of rows by unpivoted one.

Comment: I want the percent whereby I get the total count for each column where market = 'DK', and then divide the counts from the column ranges by that total. So for Bingo Turnover L90D total is 73530, and Bingo_Turnover_L90D_0 is 70474, therefore the Percent should be 70474/73530 = 95.8% and not 36%

Comment: Then you should count from BI.CMP_PRODUCT only the rows with the same type. make the select correlated.

Comment: @Serg that was a typo you named the wrong table, i have updated it

Answer (score 0):

As `TOTAL` column doesn't sum up even on `TYPE` (the sum should be exactly the number of 'DK' rows) I guess you have NULLs in `bg_turnover` column. Try include nulls in pivot.

```
...
UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS (
  bg_turnover FOR type IN (
   BINGO_TURNOVER       AS 'BINGO_TURNOVER',
   BINGO_TURNOVER_L10D  AS 'BINGO_TURNOVER_L10D',
   CASINO_TURNOVER      AS 'CASINO_TURNOVER'
   )
)
...
```

Alternatively you can use a window function to get type total

```
SELECT type ||
       CASE 
       WHEN bg_turnover = 0
       THEN '_0'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 0 AND bg_turnover <= 500
       THEN '_0_500'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 500 AND bg_turnover <= 2500
       THEN '_500_2500'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 2500 AND bg_turnover <= 5000
       THEN '_2500_5000'
       ELSE '_5000+'
       END AS BG_TURNOVER,
       count(*) AS Total, 
       Market, 
       round((count(*)/sum(count(*)) over(partition by market, type)), 2) AS Percentage,
       sum(count(*)) over(partition by market, type) typetotal
FROM   product_table 
UNPIVOT (
  bg_turnover FOR type IN (
    BINGO_TURNOVER AS 'BINGO_TURNOVER',
    BINGO_TURNOVER_L10D     AS 'BINGO_TURNOVER_L10D',
    CASINO_TURNOVER      AS 'CASINO_TURNOVER'
   ) )
where market = 'DK'
GROUP BY
       type,
       CASE 
       WHEN bg_turnover = 0
       THEN '_0'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 0 AND bg_turnover <= 500
       THEN '_0_500'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 500 AND bg_turnover <= 2500
       THEN '_500_2500'
       WHEN bg_turnover > 2500 AND bg_turnover <= 5000
       THEN '_2500_5000'
       ELSE '_5000+'
       END, Market
ORDER BY 1;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cNSfHRnm)